# text entered into textbox is not taking by safari browser in selenium webdriver for mac

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

Im using sendkeys to enter text into the text box in safari browser using selenium web driver in Mac OS. But when i try submit it it is giving error saying there is no text entered. but i can able to see the text in the textbox.

Please provide  me some suggitions for this.

Comment: Can you share some of your code and html as well?

Comment: the exception message please.

Comment: Im not getting any exception it is showing error in browser validation that there is no text

Comment: same thing is working fine in firefox . I'm facing issue only in safari browser

Comment: what is your selenium version?

Comment: selenium 2.47.1 and safari driver 2.45.0

Comment: and safari browser version?

Comment: I tried with sendkeys and javascriptexcuter to enter the text but it is not taking while submision.

Comment: Tried by giving sleep after entering text in each textbox and by setting some DesiredCapabilities but of no use

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding JavaScript Event after entering the text.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
jsExecutor.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change();", WebElement);
```